# How to update a column in Spark Dataframe based on a group of column values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Dataframe whose Department values must be from a given group of values.

```
-----------------------
Id  Name    Department
-----------------------
1   John    Sales
2   Martin  Maintenance
3   Keith   Sales
4   Rob Unknown
5   Kevin   Unknown
6   Peter   Maintenance
------------------------
```

The valid values for Department are stored in a String Array.
['Sales','Maintenance','Training']

If the Department value in the DataFrame is anything other than the allowed values, it must be replaced by 'Training'. So the new DataFrame will be -

```
-----------------------
Id  Name    Department
-----------------------
1   John    Sales
2   Martin  Maintenance
3   Keith   Sales
4   Rob     Training
5   Kevin   Training
6   Peter   Maintenance
------------------------
```

What could be a feasible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using `when/otherwise`, `concat` and `lit` inbuilt functions as

```
val validDepartments = Array("Sales","Maintenance","Training")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("Department", when(concat(validDepartments.map(x => lit(x)):_*).contains(col("Department")), col("Department")).otherwise("Training")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+------+---+-----------+
|Id |Name  |Age|Department |
+---+------+---+-----------+
|1  |John  |35 |Sales      |
|2  |Martin|34 |Maintenance|
|3  |Keith |33 |Sales      |
|4  |Rob   |34 |Training   |
|5  |Kevin |35 |Training   |
|6  |Peter |36 |Maintenance|
+---+------+---+-----------+
```

A simple `udf` function should get your requirement fulfilled too as

```
val validDepartments = Array("Sales","Maintenance","Training")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def containsUdf = udf((department: String) => validDepartments.contains(department) match {case true => department; case false => "Training"} )

df.withColumn("Department", containsUdf(col("Department"))).show(false)
```

which should give you the same result

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: hi Ramesh, Your answer was helpful. But what if validDepartments is created out of a different dataframe. It is something like -
validDepartments = someDf.select("department").collect().map(_.toString).distinct

The above will also create an Array[String]. But when I use this the containsUdf is not giving expected result. It is replacing all fields with value "Training".

Comment: the mistake is that you are calling toString on each row which would append square brackets to the rows. You can use getAs . so you can do `val validDepartments = someDf.select("department").collect().map(_.getAs[String]("department")).distinct` and  then use this validDepartments and you should be perfect ;)

Comment: Awesome. This was exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain why does validDepartments = someDf.select("department").collect().map(_.toString).distinct  given output something with brackets, even though validDepartments is of type Array[String] in both cases i.e. even when getAs is used and without it.

Comment: if you look at `Array("[Sales]", "[Training]")` and `Array("Sales", "Training")` both are `Array[String]` but you decide if they are equal or not ;)

Comment: I know both are not equal. I think I get it now why we used getAs. Thanks a lot!